# Django локал сервер проблема

Tags: sql, django, sqlite, sqlite3, django-model

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (no such table: django_site) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\views.py", line 138, in dispatch
    return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\views.py", line 78, in dispatch
    response = super(RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin,
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\views.py", line 94, in get
    response = super(AjaxCapableProcessFormViewMixin, self).get(
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 133, in get
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\views.py", line 169, in get_context_data
    site = get_current_site(self.request)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sites\shortcuts.py", line 13, in get_current_site
    return Site.objects.get_current(request)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sites\models.py", line 58, in get_current
    return self._get_site_by_id(site_id)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sites\models.py", line 30, in _get_site_by_id
    site = self.get(pk=site_id)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 411, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 258, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1151, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tests_platform-master\tests_platform-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
```

```
Exception Type: OperationalError at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: no such table: django_site
```

Comment: Миграцию выполнить забыли.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нет таблицы django_site, сделайте миграции.